# Show that $|f(x)| \leq 1$, $\forall x$. For what value of $x$ is the equality attained $f(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{n \sin x}$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $|f(x)| \leq 1$, $\forall x$. For what value of $x$ is the equality attained ?
>
> Given:
>
> 1. The function $f$: $$f(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{n \sin x},$$ with $x \neq k \pi$, $k \in \mathbb Z$, $n \in \mathbb Z^+$
>
> > Other Given(s): (from previous questions),
> >
> > 2. with $x_0$ being a local extreme point, it was found that $$ |f(x_0)| = \left[ 1 + (n^2-1) \sin^2(x_0) \right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
> > 3. $f$ is continuous at $k \pi$ when $f(k\pi)$ is defined as $(-1)^{nk-k}$

(I am not sure those "other givens" are helpful I placed it for for in case of.)
'

$$|f(x)| \leq 1  \Rightarrow   -1 \leq f(x) \leq 1$$

I have difficulty to understand here as the function is not defined at $x=k \pi$, so how can we show that $|f(x)| \leq 1$, same thing with the second part of the question.

I wanted to use the Rolle theorem but $f$ has to be continuous on a closed interval.

What would be a good approach here to solve this problem? much appreciated.

Comment: Your function (according to the given number 3) is not $\sin nx/n\sin x$ but $$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin nx}{n\sin x} & \text{if }x\neq k\pi\\
(-1)^{nk-k} & \text{if }x= k\pi
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Hint: In given number 2, you prove that if $x_0\neq k\pi$ is a **local extremum**, then is $|f(x_0)|=\cdots$ (I won't be repeating what you wrote). Use this formula to show $|f(x_0)|\leq 1$. What does this imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $x \approx 0$ then $\sin x \approx x$ hence $\frac{\sin nx}{n \sin x} \approx \frac{nx}{nx} = 1$. The point is that $f(x)$ does not blow up near multiples of $\pi$ because the behaviour in the numerator balances out that in the denominator. You can generalize this to show that $$\frac{\sin nx}{n \sin x} \approx (-1)^{kn - k}$$
when $x \approx k\pi$.

As Hamed said in the comments, $|f(x)| \le 1$ follows immediately from

$$ |f(x_0)|=\left[ 1+(n^2−1)\sin^2(x_0) \right]^{-\frac12}. $$

Note that $a^{-1/2} \le 1$ if $a \ge 1$ and $a^{-1/2} = 1$ if and only if $a = 1$.